# Can't populate arraylist in multiple choice listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, multiple-choice

I have a class who creates an Arraylist.  By this class, I add/remove objects.
I have no problem to populate a spinner, but when I come by using a listview, it is always empty.

How I populate a spinner:

```
final ArrayAdapter<Object> adapterEleves;
adapterEleves = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArraylisteEtudiants.getListe());

Spinner spinnerEtudiants = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEtudiants);
spinnerEtudiants.setAdapter(adapterEleves);
adapterEleves.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

How I try to populate a listview with multiple choices:

```
    final ArrayAdapter<Object> adapterEleves;
    adapterEleves = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ArraylisteEtudiants.getListe());

    ListView listEtudiants = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.afficherListeEtudiants);
    listEtudiants.setAdapter(adapterEleves);
    adapterEleves.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/afficherListeEtudiants"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My arraylist class:

```
public class ArraylisteEtudiants {

    final static ArrayList<Object> listeEtudiants = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public static ArrayList<Object> getListe() {

        return listeEtudiants;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: change that `ArrayList<Object>` and create a `Etudiant` class with a `toString()` method. You will be able to use a `ArrayList<Etudiant>` wherever you want and this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android reference:

**ArrayAdapter**

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references
>   a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the
>   constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should
>   reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.
>
> However the TextView is referenced, **it will be filled with the
>   toString() of each object in the array**. You can add lists or arrays of
>   custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to
>   determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

I'm pretty sure your ArrayAdapter doesn't provide a `toString()` method and that's why it will show you a blank list.

You can simply override that method in your returned object (try to use a more specific type rather than **`Object`**).

If this cannot solve your problem, you should give a try to custom ArrayAdapter, extending ArrayAdapter, personalizing the `getView()` method.